# Python Parsing an A2L file used in automotive industries

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I have a file from which i am trying to parse some data.
I am having issues in following case .

In case one if I find "NO_COMPU_METHOD" in line then I will save the word before it , which is SWORD

```
 SWORD NO_COMPU_METHOD 0 0 -32768 32767
```

In case two if I find "0 NO_COMPU_METHOD" in line then I will save the word before it , which is SSV__UWORD_Z

```
 MEAS_SMAP SSV__UWORD_Z 0 NO_COMPU_METHOD 9 0 65535zz
```

Here is the code i am trying to use

```
 import sys
 import numpy as np
 import regex

 with open('CANAPE_main.a2l', 'r') as myfile:
    print('Opening file ',myfile)
    contents = myfile.read()

 test_string = "0 NO_COMPU_METHOD "

 for x in lines:

     if 'NO_COMPU_METHOD' in x:

          match = regex.search(test_string, x)
          print(match)

          if match:
             temp0 = x.strip()
             dType = temp0.split()
             cal_var_dataType.append(dType[2])
           
          else:
             temp1 = x.strip()
             dType1 = temp1.split()
             meas_var_dataType.append(dType1[0])
```

The issue is that ,since i am using split() function, python parses "0 NO_COMPU_METHOD" as "0" and "NO_COMPU_METHOD" and hence i am facing problem . Is there any way I can parse the string with white spaces. Is there anything wrong in my regular expression code